# Frontend - Why some website change the way they look when we decrease zoom size

Tags: css, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js, flexbox

On flipkart.com when I zoom out website looks center and small, but when it comes to some other websites like oyorooms.com & paytm.com they gets expanded to whole window as shown in the image

Pls check images of 3 websites

Please someone tell me whats the difference, use flexbox for building my websites and my websites are also looking like paytm and oyo

and pls let me know what would be the correct approach[image: paytm]

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to get good habits like keeping the header tag and all of its components under one leading element such as div so that when the header changes size, all of its children elements will too. Bad HTML and CSS structure are usually the cause of these issues. Viewbox too.

Answer (score 0):

It's all based on your viewport which is the overall view of the screen you are looking at. It is the same as when you look at a website on a different device(Tablet, phone, etc...). Every website also differs with how the containers on the screen will change depending on the size(RWD, flexbox, grid, media queries). If you increase the screen to 120%, its just like you are viewing it on a larger screen size.
If any of the above terms confuse you, that's okay, I would recommend looking them up as they will be useful.
Look up viewport CSS and you will get more information on such topics.

Comment: I somehow spaced the paragraph talking about flexbox. Flexbox is based on a grid system. You can tell elements to flow on the page depending on a variety of instances(mainly size). I would recommend playing with a flexbox in codepen since it is a very useful tool to understand.  I would also recommend learning how to use CSS Grid for it is also a very powerful tool to know, including when you start using flexbox and Grid together. Just remember to use grid for the overall layout of the website, and use flexbox for the content within the elements when you use them together.

Comment: i'm using react where to change these viewports and which viewport gives me flipkart type look